# HTML5 geolocation, pass lat/long to PHP variable when page load

Tags: php, html

in this code i need to assign lat and long as a php variable .. pls help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p id="demo"></p><script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
     {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    }
    getLocation()
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: but I am new to this. I really couldn't find the solution yet

Comment: The answer is you can't.

Comment: then how can i store visitor's location in my db using html5 geolocation?

Comment: are you using mysql?

Comment: yes I am using mysql. and php

Comment: ok i will code something up and post it below. Give me 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you have a 'users' table with long and lat columns.

**somescript.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (long, lat) VALUES (:long, :lat)");
$stmt->bindParam(':long', $long);
$stmt->bindParam(':lat', $lat);
$long = $_REQUEST['long'];
$lat = $_REQUEST['lat'];
$stmt->execute();
```

**Your javascript:**

```
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position)
{
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "somescript.php?lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
getLocation();
```

similarly you would do the same for an UPDATE statement.

Comment: if my answer was helpful id appreciate you voting up or accepting the answer.

Comment: and no problem!

Comment: actually it doesnt store any value in my db

Comment: make sure the following are set correctly: servername, username, password, dbname

Comment: then alter the sql to match your table. For example, what's your table name, if it differs from users then you should change it

Comment: what are the table columns?

Comment: `long` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `sl` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sl`)

Comment: if u were to visit the url via the browser. that is: /somescript.php?lat=12.2&lng=56.8

what happens?

Comment: found the solution